# Is a terms & conditions generator good enough for my website?

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, privacy, terms-of-service

I am currently in the process of setting up a website which will include affiliate links to vendors for various products.

I've been looking into the privacy policy and terms & conditions that i'll need and i've come across services that will generate ones for you for a small fee. My concern is that these will be too generic, particularly with my site having many links to other sites and the affiliate nature of these connections.

So my question is, if these aren't enough where can I go to get something appropriate for my site?

Thanks